# Core Data: Database not reading correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm trying to load the NSData from my Core Data database but the data isn't even remotely close to what's displaying if I compare the two files, the original database vs the one saved from the NSData loaded, and the one saved from the NSData doesn't have any data in it at all, only the table structure.

Here's my source, and it's extremely basic:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

NSString *path = [AppDelegate instance].databaseDirectory.path;
NSData *file   = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
[file writeToFile:[AppDelegate instance].tempDatabaseDirectory.path atomically:NO];
```

Comment: What is your code attempting to do?  Save your MOC's changes to disk?  Because it does that, provided it's non-nil, and it's got a valid PSC.   But then there's some file system operations in the final three lines that don't make any sense unless you explain them.

Comment: @stevesliva basically, I'm just trying to get the NSData from it and upload it so it can be backed up. But for now I'm just trying to save a copy of it to the local file system, but it's only saving the scheme of it.

Comment: I think debugging this depends on those URLs and whether it's a sqlite store or not.  I know, for instance, the the sqlite store directory doesn't have just one file in it.

Comment: Well when I copy the directory of the database to my documents folder, and just the .sqlite file, and open that in DB Browser for SQLite on my Mac, everything shows it fine. It's pretty annoying

Comment: There are two other files you need to backup, in addition to the `....sqlite` file: `....sqlite-wal` and `....sqlite-shm`.  These are journal files which store the database updates.